# Read local package/bower.json file to check the app version

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs

I want to do some conditional operations inside my angularjs application for different versions of my app. How do I `import` the `version` property of my bower/package.json file from my Angular app locally.

I seem to get `module not found`error when trying to import the json file (actually anything that's not .ts file). I am not planning to use $http.get(..) to read the json file asynchronously nor installing node/express packages to use `require` module.
I want to simply use the ES6 or SystemJS module loader for doing this task. Thank you :)

Comment: actually I can use asynchronous reading ($http.get or fetch or async..await) now. any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution in AngularJS Controller:

```
var appVersion = require('electron').remote.app.getVersion();
```

Comment: this is not effective as it requires to install electron and requirejs. I found that `var appVersion = require("./package.json!json")` might work if planning on using requirejs. But with systemjs, to postfix the module-require call, adding `meta: {
        "*.json": { "loader": "json" }
    }` in the metaconfig file seems to do the trick. I will check it soon